# What would cause "Name Model is not declared" inside an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a class library that has an ado.net entity data model and some repository classes to interact with the data.  I added a reference to this class library in my MVC project.  When I create a strongly typed view in the MVC project, I have the option of selecting one of the classes from my class library reference.  The view is created successfully and inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of IEnumerable (Of MyClassLibraryNamespace.MyClass)).  So far so good - but the Model object in the view is not recognized.  In the view, the line of code "For each item in Model" will not compile because "Model is not declared."  Can I not base a view on an object outside of the current project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use an object outside of the current project. You need to make sure you have put a reference to that other project (assembly) in your web projects references to do this though.

Comment: I did add a reference to the other project.  I can see the other project's classes in the drop down list when I am creating a view and selecting a class to base the view on.

Comment: have you fully qualified your object? It needs to be. If you have added the reference then a spelling mistake or not fully qualifying your class is all I can think would cause that problem